# How to store closures in a Swift array

Tags: swift

I would like to store closures in an array. But I have no clue how to do it, or my thinking is totally wrong. With setup shown below I got an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Reader) -> (URL) -> ()' to expected element type '(URL) -> ()'
```

I don't understand it. My class:

```
class Reader {
    let fileNamesActions:[( filename:String, action:(URL) -> () )]  = [
        (filename:"goodStories.txt", action: readGoodStories),
        (filename:"badStories.txt", action: readBadStories),
        (filename:"stupidStories", action: readStupidStories)]
```

I have declared functions like this:

```
    func readGoodStories(from url:URL) {
        //read, do whatever i want with url
    }
    ...
```

And I call them by:

```
    init (with url:URL) {    
         for (filename, action) in fileNamesActions {
             action(url.appendingPathComponent(filename))
         }
     }
```

Comment: I thin the problem is that your functions (‘readGoodStories’, ...) are defined in class Reader. You need define them out of that class or change ‘let fileNamesActions:[( filename:String, action:(URL) -> () )]’ to ‘let fileNamesActions:[( filename:String, action:(Reader) -> (URL) -> () )]’

Comment: But what to do if I need them inside Reader Class?

Comment: You need to change ‘let fileNamesActions:[( filename:String, action:(URL) -> () )]’ to ‘let fileNamesActions:[( filename:String, action:(Reader) -> (URL) -> () )]’

Comment: Default initialization runs before `self` is available, thus `readGoodStories` is not yet matchable to `self`. Try making `fileNamesActions` a computed property.

Comment: I have tried. But line `action(url.appendingPathComponent(filename))` shouts "Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'UFOFont' "

Comment: I edited a post. Indeed, I'm calling functions before self is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change declaration of `fileNamesActions` as `lazy var` because you are accessing the `class` members in its assignment,

```
class Reader {

    lazy var fileNamesActions:[( filename:String, action:(URL) -> () )]  = [
        (filename:"goodStories.txt", action: readGoodStories),
        (filename:"badStories.txt", action: readBadStories),
        (filename:"stupidStories", action: readStupidStories)]

    init (with url:URL) {
        for (filename, action) in fileNamesActions {
            action(url.appendingPathComponent(filename))
        }
    }

    func readBadStories(from url:URL) {
        print(url.path)
    }

    func readStupidStories(from url:URL) {
        print(url.path)
    }

    func readGoodStories(from url:URL) {
        print(url.path)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let reader = Reader(with: URL(string: "www.xxxxxxxxxx.com")!)
```

**Output**

```
www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/goodStories.txt
www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/badStories.txt
www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/stupidStories
```